# Function to preview a chunk of html in the RStudio viewer pane

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I'd like to preview/render a generated piece of html in the rstudio viewer pane, without having to knit the entire rmarkdown document

For example:

```r
preview_html(mtcars %>% kable(format = "html"))
```

generates a block of HTML. I'd like it to be rendered in the preview pane.

Answer (score 1):

The following function writes a temporary html file with just the code chunk, and opens it in the viewer:

```r
preview_html <- function(code){
  tempDir <- tempfile()
  dir.create(tempDir)
  htmlFile <- file.path(tempDir, "index.html")
  writeLines(paste0('<html><body>',
                    code,
                    '</body></html>'), htmlFile)
  viewer <- getOption("viewer")
  viewer(htmlFile)
}

preview_html(mtcars %>% kable(format = "html")) # Opens in viewer pane
```

Comment: how to preview an image?